# Free reporting library for PHP without installation?

Tags: php, report

Is there a good (and hopefully free?) source library to use for PHP for creating and displaying reports? I would love one that would allow the user to view it in a nice format for saving and printing (like PDF?).

Also I would prefer one that is just files, not one that needs to be installed on the server itself as some of the people I create sites for are on shared server hosts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if you would call this reporting but I have found these gems over the years:

- http://pchart.sourceforge.net/
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/4044-Dynamically-Generating-PDF-Files-with-PHP-and-Haru-
- http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/
- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprtf/
- http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/index.en.php
- http://www.maani.us/charts4/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/
- http://code.google.com/p/ofcgwt/w/list
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpreports/ <-- Just found this

Comment: The first one is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pdf generating library for PHP http://www.fpdf.org/ .

Comment: looks like a good add-in for at least getting a pdf. thanks. still hoping to get something like the Dundas reports:

http://www.dundas.com/Microsite/ChartNETB/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at a few in the past, here is 2 that I recall (and was able to search for quick):

- http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/repgen/

PHP Reportmaker is pretty good. Not sure if it fits the bill of what you want tho.
Examples are here:
http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/features.asp

Comment: Is phpreportmaker only available for Windows OS? It seems odd but the download page makes it sound that way? Otherwise I like the look and tools of this one.

Answer (score 0):

FPDF combined with PHPMyGraph for creating bars etc.:
http://phpmygraph.abisvmm.nl/